# How can i configure the macOS firewall to access my docker nginx container?

Tags: nginx, docker

MacOS firewall is preventing me from accessing my docker nginx container

I can use my domain name to get to non-docker nginx running on my laptop.

I cannot use my domain name to get to docker nginx running on my laptop unless I disable the macOS firewall.

- docker nginx is running on port 80
- docker nginx is accessible with curl localhost

When I turn off my macOS firewall I can access my docker nginx.

How can i configure the macOS firewall to access my docker nginx container?

Comment: This might be helpful http://serverfault.com/questions/183542/how-to-permanently-redirect-port-80-to-8080-on-os-x/235124#235124

Comment: A workaround (and maybe the solution) is to use non-docker nginx as a reverse proxy pointing to the port that docker makes available.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons but since it works when the Firewall is OFF, my answer focuses on allowing Docker on MacOS firewall. Also, these steps could look different based on the MacOS version.

### Reason A: If the Firewall is blocking the Docker Application to receive incoming connection all together

We want to force Docker to popup and ask to be allowed in the Firewall. I find this option easier, however, you can do it manual as well. First quit Docker and Go to the Firewall settings under Mac Preferences. It's under Network option but find it based on your Mac flavor.

What we essentially want is to allow **com.docker.backend** in the firewall. You can find it if you right click on Docker in the `Application -> Show Package Contents -> Contents -> MacOS -> com.docker.backend`

#### Option 1

1. Turn Off 'Automatically allow built-in....' and 'Automatically allow downlaoded...' options. Save the settings.
2. Now start Docker. It should give a prompt to be allowed. Allow it.
3. Validate that **com.docker.backend** is added in the list and is 'Allow incoming connection'.

#### Option 2

If you don't see **com.docker.backend** in the list. Set Docker to auto start on Login and restart Mac. Post login, it should give you a popup again. Allow now and Validate if it appears.

#### Option 3

You can also click on the + icon in the Firewall settings and select Docker from the Applications. However, I don't recommend doing it because it brings everything in the Docker Application package.

### Reason B: If the Firewall is blocking the incoming call on the IP and/or Port you are exposing

You are gonna need to use `pfctl` and forward ports as required. There are better answers on SO than I can write. Check this:
https://superuser.com/questions/473039/pfctl-port-forwarding-in-mac-osx

*Btw, I assumed that the Docker container is properly bound to the IP and Port on the host.*

Answer (score -1):

macOS is failing to recognize the connection attempts to ask if it should allow them.

We added `app: bundleid = com.ht.kubecontext` to allow in the firewall config on macOS and magically connections worked. Not sure if this is a bug in docker.app not including kube connections to its context when enabled or a macOS sensing failure, but this unblocked us on the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Here are the settings which will prevent MacOS firewall from blocking :

```
Ngnix port > 8000
Public Port : 80
```